# Necessity of Brackets for Integration

Tags: integration, notation

Suppose I want to integrate $f(x)+g(x)$. Can this be written as
$\int f(x)+g(x)\, dx$
or are brackets necessary, i.e. 
$\int \left(f(x)+g(x)\right) \,dx$?

Comment: It depends on how fussy or easily confused your readers are.  From my point of view, explicit brackets remove possible ambiguity, but there are implicit brackets between $\int$ and $dx$ especially when there is a single integration.

Comment: If you believe your readers might have to pause, err on the side of additional parentheses. This isn't like sending a telegraph; nobody meters the use of parentheses in an expression...

Comment: I tend to think the brackets are necessary.  The $dx$ in an integral is not just a placeholder -- it's a small increment of $x$ that you're *multiplying* by the function.

Comment: I fail to see how the version without parenthesis could make sense. If anybody knows references of texts using this convention, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

But be careful that in general
$$\int f(x) +g(x) d x \neq \int f(x) d x + \int g(x) d x.$$

E.g. consider the integral over $\mathbb{R}$ with $f=1$ and $g(x)=-1$ times the indicator function of $|x| >1$.

Comment: Another one: $\int_0^z \left(\frac1{u}-\frac{\cos\,u}{u}\right)\mathrm du$ is sensible; the split version, not so much...

Comment: @late_learner Is your $g=\chi_{|x|>1}(x)$?

Comment: Depends on your definition;) but probably yes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conventional exception.  If I were going to write $(f(x)+g(x))\,dx$, with no integral sign (e.g. when a differential equation is written as $a(x,y)\,dx+b(x,y)\,dy=0$ and the expression $a(x,y)$ or $b(x,y)$ has several terms) I would not omit the parentheses.  Everything within the parentheses is multiplied by $dx$.  If $f(x)+g(x)$ is in meters per second and $dx$ is in seconds, then $(f(x)+g(x))\,dx$.  However, in something like $\displaystyle\int x^2+3x+10 \, dx$ it is quite conventional to omit delimeters.  It is as if the expression
$$
\int \cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots dx
$$
acts in some way on whatever is written where "$\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$" appears.