# Parenthesis in integral necessary?

Tags: integration, notation

Im arguing with some friends whether it is necessary to put parenthesis around a sum in an integral: can we write $\int_a^b x^2+x ~ \mathrm d x$ or do we need to write $\int_a^b(x^2+x)\mathrm d x$?

My friends are arguing that we are not integrating $f$ but rather the differential form $f\cdot \mathrm d x$. Since this is a product we need parenthesis if $f$ is replaced by a sum.

My argument is, that i see the integral as an operator $\int_a^b \cdot \mathrm dx: L^1\to\mathbb C$, so the full notation would be $\int_a^b (x\mapsto x^2+x)dx$. Both of the suggestions above would then just be shortcuts to save some time and the necessity of paranthesis would then just be an arbitrary cut of how much of a shortcut is allowed.

I think both arguments do have some validation.

So my questions: Do we need them or don't we?

Comment: I go with your argument. We don't.(that's what our prof said atleast..)

Comment: Makes no sense without parenthesis.

Comment: [It depends](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132103/necessity-of-brackets-for-integration)

Comment: Well to be honest I go both ways since $\int f(x)$ doesn't make sense so if given $\int f(x) + g(x) \, dx$, I always assume that you have to integrate both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. But, as a precaution, I always write it as $\int \left( f(x) + g(x) \right) \, dx$

Comment: My two cents: if there's any doubt, use parentheses. Better to be told that you have redundant notation than to be told that you have confusing notation.

Comment: It is good manners to use $(\cdot)$ IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "need parentheses for sum because $f~dx$ is a product" argument, though noble, fails for <strike>two</strike> $\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\epsilon+1$ reasons:

- The 'factors' in the product aren't interchangeable: you can't write $\displaystyle\int~dx~f(x)$ ... well, you can, but <strike>nobody</strike> possibly only physicists :-) will understand what you mean.
- With double and triple integrals, the integrals and differentials behave like parentheses, e.g. $\displaystyle\int_0^2\int_0^{2\pi}r^2\theta+\theta~d\theta~dr$ is effectively
  $\displaystyle\int_0^2\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\vphantom{\int}r^2\theta+\theta\right)~d\theta\right)~dr$. You can't reorder the differentials without changing the meaning.

  > **Edit**: physicists, at least, **do** write multiple integrals with leading differentials (see comments below); it's possible to assign a well-defined meaning to integrals written this way and which *would* require the trailing expression to be parenthesised if it were a sum rather than a product - c.f. $\cos2\theta$ vs. $\cos(2\theta+\pi)$. That style treats $\displaystyle\int~dx$ like a function or operator, as per the OP's suggestion, and does not treat the differential as a factor in a product as put forth by the OP's friends (the placement of the differentials matters as it would not in a true product).

Comment: I have consistently written my integrals with the $dx$ leading and people seem to get what I mean.  In fact, multiple integrals are much more easily understood with the differential first.

Comment: @RonGordon: I could well be living in a small world of limited experience. Are there examples of the leading differential style in the literature?

Comment: Yes: in the 19th century literature!

Comment: Yeah, look in any physics journal or textbook.  You are likely to see plenty of examples.

Comment: @RonGordon: Just checked "Introduction to Electrodynamics" (Griffiths), "Introduction to Particle and Astroparticle Physics" (De Angelis, João, Pimenta) ... all standard ... aha!  Found what appear to be examples in "Symmetries in Fundamental Physics" (Sundermeyer). Man, that's scary mathematics! There are integrals there I can't even *parse*!